# Robotframework - How can I select this type of radio button by means of the text in its associated label?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, radio-button, robotframework

I am unable to write a task/keyword which can select this type of radio button by means of its associated text label. In this specific case: **common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0**

Library used: [**SeleniumLibrary 4.4.0**](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html)
Desired behavior: **Click Element** or **Select Radio Button**

```
<div style="width:96%; display: flex">
  <div class="radio template-radio ng-scope" tooltip="" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="top" style="max-width: 100%"><input id="45725" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.$parent.selectedPolicyTemplate" value="45725" ng-disabled="!templateCanBeApplied(template)" required="required" class="ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="1464">
    <label class="policy-name ng-binding" for="45725" data-test-id="policy-template-name" ng-style="{'max-width': template.custom ? '80%' : '100%'}" ng-class="{'text-disabled': !templateCanBeApplied(template)}" title="common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0" style="max-width: 80%;">common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0</label><!-- ngIf: template.custom -->
    <span ng-if="template.custom" class="label label-default ng-scope" style="margin-left: 4px">Custom</span><!-- end ngIf: template.custom -->
  </div>
<div style="width:2%"><i class="fa fa-info-circle info-icon ng-scope" style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 8px" tooltip="Initialize response headers data in session variables" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom"></i></div></div>
```

Here is a visual reference.

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This was the solution for my problem**

```
Wait Until Element is Enabled   //*[@class="modal-body ap-resource-level-policies ng-scope"]
${for_value}=   Get Element Attribute      //label[@title="common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0"]      for
Execute Javascript      document.getElementById("${for_value}").click()
```

***Hope it helps others. Cheers***

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the head up (once again JS to the rescue). During your tests, did you try `Select Radio Button` option ? Curious to see if it works with `Select Radio Button 1464 45725`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using `Selenium2Library` and you want to click (use `Get WebElement`otherwise) on the element you can use :

```
Click Element //input[@type="radio"][following-sibling::label[1][.="common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0"]]
```

Look for an `input` element followed directly with a specific sibling (`label` element with content equals to "common...").

Old syntax :

```
Click Element xpath: //input[@type="radio"][following-sibling::label[1][.="common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0"]]
```

EDIT : If you face exception errors, add an expected condition before the click :

```
Wait Until Element Is Enabled xpath: //input[@type="radio"][following-sibling::label[1][.="common-response-headers-policy-v1.0.0"]]
```

Comment: I get the following message: ```ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)```

Comment: OK. Post is edited. What's the ouput if you add an expected condition ?

Comment: Same result  `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: I tried with `Mouse Down` instead and receiving this following error: `JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.`